# Upload images on data lake store using u sql

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I need to upload multiple images from my local folder to Azure Data lake store.

I was looking on link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2016/08/18/introducing-image-processing-in-u-sql/

I am able to get detail of images, but i also want to upload multiple images on Azure Data lake store.
Please suggest, is it possible in U SQL or i need to use any other approach for the same?
It would be great if you will share any reference link for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell

```
# Log in to your Azure account
Login-AzureRmAccount

# Modify variables as required
$DataLakeStoreAccount =  #"<yourAccountNameHere>";
$DataLakeStorePath = "/Samples/Data";
$destinationFile = "/Samples/Data/Test.txt";
$localFile = "C:\Temp\Test.txt";


# upload file
Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $DataLakeStoreAccount -Path $localfile -Destination $destinationFile;
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/import-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-3.8.0

#verify
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -AccountName $DataLakeStoreAccount -Path $DataLakeStorePath;
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/get-azurermdatalakestorechilditem?view=azurermps-3.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a link to the documentation that explains this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk#upload-a-file